# Do I start a new paragraph after someone is finished speaking?

Tags: dialogue

If I were to be writing a paper in first person and someone other than the main character says something and then no one else says anything, should I start a new paragraph or keep writing in the same paragraph?  For example if I was writing:

> “I hope so,” some of them say.  It is a short period of time before we are set down again.

Would I write it like that or like this:

> I hope so,” some of them say.
>
> It is a short period of time before we are set down again.

Comment: Going off what the first linked question says, I would go with the latter because the focus of the sentence is different from the focus of the dialogue.